# AttributeError: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'session'

Tags: django, session, middleware, django-middleware, django-sessions

I keep getting this error at random times and whenever I touch the django.wsgi file, it gets fixed only to happen again after a few hours. I'm lost as to what to do. my middleware_classes is as follows:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.cache.UpdateCacheMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfResponseMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.facebookConnectMiddleware.FacebookConnectMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.cache.FetchFromCacheMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.flatpages.middleware.FlatpageFallbackMiddleware',
)
```

The error always occurs in the facebook middleware when i do an "if request.session" statement. 
Thanks

Comment: Have you solved this? And how?

Answer (score 6):

Make sure the SessionMiddleware is first in your `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES`.

Comment: Starting from Django 2.0 `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` is replaced with `MIDDLEWARE` - [more here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39480179/wsgirequest-object-has-no-attribute-session-while-upgrading-from-django-1-3)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Apache?  If so, you should probably restart httpd after you modify the mod_wsgi file.

```
sudo apachectl -k restart
sudo apache2ctl -k restart
sudo /etc/init.d/httpd restart
```

... or similar should work.  If you're still seeing the problem, try pasting in the full error message.

Comment: Whether a full Apache restart is required is dependent on how you are using mod_wsgi. If using daemon mode there are ways of restarting application code without restarting the whole of Apache. See 'http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ReloadingSourceCode'.

Comment: True enough.  I'm diagnosing the symptoms a bit here: typically when I see a problem recur it's because it's fixed in one Apache thread but not in all of them ... hence the restart idea.  It's worth a try :-)

Comment: i restarted apache and that seemed to do the trick. thank you both for your input :-)

Comment: nope.. the problem occurred again. entering the url without an ending slash gives the error and it only gets fixed temporarily when i touch django.wsgi..what to do..

Comment: What does your wsgi file look like?  and your urls.py?

Comment: I have the same problem in the development server so it's probably not apache related.

Answer (score 0):

Try the alternate WSGI script file documented at end of:

http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2010/03/improved-wsgi-script-for-use-with.html

Report back to mod_wsgi list if that helps as we are trying still to uncover what if any problems that alternate WSGI script is solving, so can work out whether a real problem or whether users aren't using Django properly.

Answer (score 0):

Check if in your code you have write:

> del request.session

the correctly are is

> del request.session['YOU VARIABLE']