# 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'session' while upgrading from django 1.3 to 1.9

Tags: python, django, django-middleware

Similar to this question ['WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'session'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11783404/wsgirequest-object-has-no-attribute-session)

But my MIDDLEWARE classes are in the correct order.

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'membership',
    'treebeard',
    'haystack',
    'reversion',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

I am redirecting to login

```py
url(r'^$',  RedirectView.as_view(url='login/')),
url(r'^login/$', 'membership.views.loginView', name='login'),
```

and then

```py
def loginView(request):
    a = request.session
```

Throws the error

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`MIDDLEWARE` is a new setting in 1.10 that will replace the old `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES`.

Since you're currently on 1.9, Django doesn't recognize the `MIDDLEWARE` setting. You should use the `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` setting instead:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

Comment: Django 2.0 uses `MIDDLEWARE` now instead of `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES`, as pointed out by @Slipstream 
 and [in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47650447/1218179)

Answer (score 18):

**Django 2.0**

You can try this in your settings.py, MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [....]:

- Change **MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES**=[...] to **MIDDLEWARE**=[...]
- Remove **SessionAuthenticationMiddleware** from the MIDDLEWARE=[...] list.

> The MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES setting is deprecated in Django 1.10, and
> removed in Django 2.0.
>
> The SessionAuthenticationMiddleware class is removed. It provided no
> functionality since session authentication is unconditionally enabled
> in Django 1.10.

Answer (score 6):

This error can also be thrown when you have a typo. i.e.

```
request.sesion ...
```

instead of

```
request.session ...
```

Comment: I was laughing when I read your possible solution! Then I checked and I had done the exact same typo. Now I am laughing in tears

Comment: And it's request.session, not request.sessions..... :(

Comment: haha, same here, I did with 3s

Comment: same here! hahhaa

Answer (score 3):

Check the order of the middleware, if you are trying to access it on some middlewares which are listed above the session middleware, you will get this error.